# Crontab command w/ output specification for exporting PNG from Bokeh

Tags: python, cron, bokeh

I need advice regarding Bokeh - Python visualization library running on Linux, saving plot via export_png function. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html

When manually executing script, png is being exported as expected. But scheduled cronjob script, doesn't generate PNG file.
This post was very helpful: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bokeh-export-png-svg/2685/4. I added to crontab the line specifying phantomjs location: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

My actual cron command:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
1 * * * * python3 /home/airflow/airflow/tasks/ta_auto/screener.py
```

I have tried many variations w/ output file path included:

```
 1 * * * * python3 /home/airflow/airflow/tasks/ta_auto/screener.py > /home/airflow/airflow/data/plot.png
```

But since the file path of output file is included in export_png function call, answer will be probably elsewhere:

```
export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```

Please advise how to achieve exporting PNG to desired location with proper cronjob command. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add a lot of detail to your question. What is the line in crontab? How do you know it is not working? What have you tried so far? Why is phantomjs relevant? There are many ways to do what you're asking, and many examples available on the Internet. To help you, we need to narrow down your issue.

Comment: crontab usually run code as different user, with different privileges, different enviroment settings, in different folder then you may expect - all for security reason. So use full pathes to python, script and folders - ie. `/usr/bin/python /home/my/script.py > /var/output.txt`. You can also use folders with privileges for all users - like `var`. You can also use `logging` module and write messages in file. At start you can create script which write information about used user and folder to see what settings crontab uses.

Comment: thank you @furas, I will do my research about crontab default user settings

Comment: I believe cron runs jobs in your home directory... have you done a `cd ~` and an `ls` to check that it hasn't been output to your home directory?

Comment: That `PATH` line looks copied form the linked post. Did you check that `phantomjs` is actually installed in one of those directories (and not some place else) on your system?

Comment: Yes, I checked. PhantomJS is is same path as in mentioned post. @bigreddot

Comment: Kevin yes, its not in default user home directory

Comment: I think you will have to investigate how to get log output from a cron job. There's some sort of system misconfiguration but I don't see any way of finding out what it might be without more information.

Comment: Regular cron output logs are exported to /var/log/syslog.
Syslog says that script is being run by user airflow, as by default cron commands are saved as user cron command, not root.

Comment: CRON[17834]: (airflow) CMD (/home/airflow/pipeline/bin/python /home/airflow/airflow/tasks/ta_auto/screener.py)

Comment: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: these lines I always get logged, afaik (No MTA installed, discarding output) is stdout and doesn't have anything to do with exporting png

Answer (score 0):

Solution was adding enviroment variables in cron command:

```
25 * * * * . $HOME/.profile; python /home/path/to/script/script.py
```